# Windows 7 Re-imaging

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I created a system image via the built-in tools for Windows 7 and stored that image on an external drive. In trying to use the System Repair disc I also created from 7 (albeit at a different time) to restore the image to the same box, it is telling me it can't find the image. The odd part with this is if I click "Advanced" on the "Re-image your computer" dialog and then "Install a driver" on the prompt, I can see the external disk as an option to select the driver from (implying Windows sees the disk the image is on). Further, when I navigate into the "WindowsImageBackup" folder I've confirmed I can get to where the image is without any problems which confirms it isn't a permissions issue.

Any tips on how to do this restore? The box in question currently has the Windows 8 CP installed on it and I'm just trying to revert back to my previous Windows 7 install temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-image-restore-refuses-to-recognize/43a29e5a-b1a3-4097-a254-2af0239ade88

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/can-i-move-a-windows-system-image-backup-to/f9ec0ad5-c409-407b-bd1a-1421dcd9d0a2

You're not the only one with this problem.  It would seem the WindowsImageBackup folder wants to be at the root of the drive and the files inside need to have their original names or it acts up.

I've personally never used the utility, I just have mad Google skillz.

Comment: Looks like I'm screwed then. The backup is in the root of the drive (inside the WindowsImageBackup folder). There are a couple of other backups in there for other systems so I'm trying to move those elsewhere so only one backup exists when it scans. Something tells me that won't work, but it's the only hope I've got left before I don't bother.